# What type of Bianchi do I own?

Tags: identify-this-bike

I bought this 2 years ago from a man with a lot of bicycles. It has straight handlebars and the number HOL3 1703 at the bottom of the bike. Thanks for the help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1 because you took useful photos and included them in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it says on the top tube, it's a Bianchi Main Street.

Looks like an older hybrid (probably early 90s).

Would do fine for riding around town possibly after a bit of a tune up.

Comment: Thanks. I'm thinking about selling and buying a larger bike (I'm 6'4"). I had it tuned up 18 months ago and haven't riden it more than maybe 200 miles. I also had new tires places on it - Panaracer Pasela PT 700x35c (35-622). 

What would you sell it for?

Comment: @Bluegrass Sorry but we don't give item valuations.

Comment: Yeah ; among other things it doesn’t help others and is highly market dependent. The answer is basically what people will pay.